# How can I know how much space software takes?

Tags: debian, partition

I am using debian (unstable). My system was partitioning with 9 GiB for /. This is not enough for me and I use already 7,5 GiB.

I don't want (for now) to use gparted in order to repartitioning (it takes a while and could be dangerous).

Therefore, I am looking a way to see how much space softwares takes. I guess LaTeX takes a lot of space but, perhaps, I have (big) softwares installed which I don't need. I would like a list by size and I don't how to have this information.